# Can't read a property value from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to get the value from the property **Success** but I can't, I don't know where I'm wrong.

This is my code

```
DECLARE @Response VARCHAR(8000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Result xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">    
    <Success>true</Success>  
</Result>'

DECLARE @xml TABLE (
    Content XML
)

INSERT INTO @xml
SELECT CAST(@Response AS XML)

SELECT
    Content.value('(/Result/Success)[1]', 'BIT')
FROM @xml
```

The property **Success** is bool type

[image]

I'm trying with different scope types (nvarchar, varchar, bit, etc..)

This is what I expecting

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Your element is inside the `http://tempuri.org/` default namespace, so you'll need to declare that: `WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/') SELECT...`. Don't forget to terminate your statements with `;`.

Comment: thanks a lot Jeroen Mostert, I spend a couple of hours with this problem, your comment is simple and helpful, thanks again.

Comment: If Jereon doesn't want to add an answer feel free to add your own and self accept (but please don't change the title to say solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- It is always better to use XML data type instead of the VARCHAR(..) for XML
  data.
- All XML elements are bound to the default namespace even if we don't
  see it explicitly. That's why we need to specify it via
  `XMLNAMESPACES` clause.
- It is always better to use `text()` in the XPath expressions for XML
  elements for performance reasons. Peculiarity of the MS SQL Server.
- It is possible to omit XML prolog declaration completely. SQL Server
  doesn't store it.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @Response XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Result xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">    
    <Success>true</Success>  
</Result>';

DECLARE @xml TABLE (Content XML);

INSERT INTO @xml
SELECT @Response;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/')
SELECT result = Content.value('(/Result/Success/text())[1]', 'BIT')
FROM @xml;
```

**Output**

| result |
| --- |
| 1 |